# django can't relabel empty label in TypedChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I can't seem to relabel the empty label in a form's ModelChoiceField. 
I have tried. (note I am using django crispy forms for the form layout - shouldn't interfere with this)

Forms.py

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['payment_day'].empty_label = 'test something'
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.label_class = 'sr-only'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            ......
            PrependedText('payment-day', '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>', placeholder="What"),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = DirectDebit
        fields = [
                  ......
                  'payment_day',
                  ]
```

models.py

```
class DirectDebit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ......

    DAYS_OF_MONTH_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(32)]
    payment_day = models.IntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_MONTH_CHOICES)

    time_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Updated title to correctly name TypedChoiceField instead of ModelChoiceField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
self.fields['payment_day'].choices = [('', '---- Please select your payment day ----')] + list(
            self.fields['payment_day'].choices[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you set `empty_label` it may be too late, as the field's choices have already been calculated. Try reassigning the queryset to itself, to see whether that triggers the choices to be recalculated.

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
self.fields['payment_day'].empty_label = 'test something'
self.fields['payment_day'].queryset = self.fields['payment_day'].queryset
```

Comment: Thanks, currently I get a `TypedChoiceField' object has no attribute 'queryset'` error

Comment: You put ModelChoiceField in your question title, so I assumed that it's a ModelChoiceField. TypedChoicdFields don't even have an empty_label option.